# Find string using regex

Tags: regex

Given the following output:

```
object = {"ajax_url":"https:\/\/gg.se\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php","security":"795fg41165"};
anotherObject = {"ajax_url":"https:\/\/gg.se\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php","security":"7556ty23456"};
```

How can I find the value 795fg41165 using regex?

Comment: Yes, thats right

Comment: Something like starts with object ^object and in the fourth ""

Comment: Try this: https://regex101.com/r/kIFtnC/1